# Filtering MongoDB collections within collection using MongoDB Shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-shell

Apologies for the nood question. I'm just starting out using MongoDB and MongoDB Shell.

I've got a DB called Dealers that looks a little like this (very simplified):

```
        [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Vehicles": [
        {
            "Manufacturer": "Ford"
        },
        {
            "Manufacturer": "MG"
        },
        {
            "Manufacturer": "Citroen"
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Vehicles": [
        {
            "Manufacturer": "Ford"
        },
        {
            "Manufacturer": "Nissan"
        },
        {
            "Manufacturer": "Ford"
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

I'm trying to get my head round how you filter collections within collections EG. Say I wanted to select all the Ford's from Id 2.

I get as far as:

```
const dealer = database.collection('Dealers');
const result = await dealer.find({Id: 2})
```

and I tried:

```
const result = await dealers.find({
    Id: 2,
    Vehicles: [
        {
            Manufacturer: "Ford"
        }
    ]
})
```

But I know that won't work because it's not iterating through the Vehicles collection. Is this the sort of instance that you would use an aggregation? Like I say, I'm very new to this sort of environment, and would really appreciate any pointers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just have tried. You can use **Aggregate function** To actually match the items inside the array in the collection. Like the way following query will select all the documents that have id equal to 1 and Manufacturer equal to Ford

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate([{$match:{Id:1}},{$unwind:"$Vehicles"}, {$match: {"Vehicles.Manufacturer":"Ford"}}]);
```

It is returning like this. I have used my own Id i.e equal to one you can change this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was just what I needed. Put me on the right path.